# linux read sys call doesnt get EOF

Tags: c, linux, io, pipe, eof

First of all sorry if my English won't be fluent and clear.

I'm working on understanding pipes and communication between processes. I have tried to implement two c programs, the one writes into a certain pipe from what he reads from the standard input and the other one waits until the pipe opens and reads from it and prints to the standard output until EOF.

Here is the code for the writer pipe:

```
  fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
  if(fd == -1) print_error();

  while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
    if(write(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) == -1) print_error();
  }
```

and here is the code for the reader pipe:

```
while(1) {
    if((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
      if(errno == ENOENT) sleep(1);
      else print_error();
    }
    else {
      while(read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
      }
    }
  }
```

The thing is that when I run those two programs concurrently the basic concept works, I write something to the standard input in the writer program and I see in the other terminal that the reader program prints it to the standard output. The problem is that when I send EOF by hitting CTRL + D for the writer program the reader program still waits for input, and I know for sure that it isn't because the while(1), I saw in the debugger that the read syscall is just waiting to input and didn't understand that we got EOF, the line : `read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)` didn't evaluate even though there is no input.

I hope that I gave all the data needed to solve the problem, anyone have any ideas what gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fgets()` detects `EOF` it returns either what already is in its read buffer or just returns `NULL`.

In the latter case you want to notify the reading end that the transmission is over by for example just closing  the pipe.

```
  int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
  if (fd == -1) 
  {
    perror("open() failed");
  }
  else
  {    
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
      if (write(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) == -1) 
      {
        perror("write() failed");
        break;
      }
    }
    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
       perror("fgets() failed");
    }

    close(fd); /* The other end's blocking call to read() would return 0. */
  }
```

In no case something like `EOF` is read. `EOF` is not a character but a state.

From [`man 3 read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> If  some  process  has the pipe open for writing [...] `read()` shall block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe
>             open for writing.

---

Also this code does not cover `read()`  failing:

```
  while(read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
  }
```

It should look for example like this:

```
  ssize_t result;
  while (0 != (result = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE))) 
  {
    if (0 > result)
    {
      if ((EINTR == errno) || (EAGAIN == errno)) 
      {
        continue;
      }

      perror("read() failed");
      break;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
  }
```

---

Even more this loop ...

```
while(1) {
  if((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
    if(errno == ENOENT) sleep(1);
    else print_error();
  }
  ...
}
```

... misses to `close()` `fd`, before (re-)opening it.

---

If the reader does not write let it open the pipe by specifying `O_RDONLY` instead of `RDWR`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer, the thing is that in the end of the program I do close the pipe but with no help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, giving a more robust code snippet for the reading end. @C.MerabiShmulik

Comment: Okay, I'm checking that, and there are no errors. The thing is that I'm sure that the writer program closes the pipe. The only other process that uses the pipe as well is the reader program, is it possible that because of him I'm waiting?

Comment: The reader process **also** opens the pipe for **writing**. Read the man page closely: "*... or the pipe is closed by **all** processes that had the pipe **open for writing**.*"

Comment: OHHHH! that makes sense, I'll try fixing that right now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`read` can also return `-1` on error. This might be the case if your writer process doesn't close his output stream properly. So you should definitively check for read `<= 0`.

But I hope that you are also aware that your surrounding `while(1)` loop will make it immediately enter the `read` call for a next round, so it might also be that you see just that.

Comment: That wasn't the problem, but thanks anyway for trying to help.